# IR2104 MOSFET driver

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have a simple circuit, where I want to use a MOSFET (IRF8010) as a switch. I have a microcontroller which produces a 3.3V PWM output @ 500Hz and will be used to control the MOSFET. Obviously, driving the MOSFET gate directly from the μP was not an option (very low output current, slow gate charging), and I was told that the best solution to drive the MOSFET was a driver, like IR2104. Having searched the internet, I could only find detailed information about using the IR2104 for H-bridges and Motors.

How should I use the IR2104 in my case?

Comment: IR2104 has low and high side drivers, you can use another option that only has a low side driver if that's all you need.

Comment: Determine the switching speed you need, keeping in mind that very fast switching causes horrid inductive spikes in GND wires and possible oscillation of the power driver. Compute the driver output current needed. I = C * dV/dT Ensure the FET gate is driven well above the turn-on threshold; if 5 volt gate, use a 9v or 12v voltage. (some FETS are 5v compatible, meaning the threshold is very low, and will be vulnerable to inductive upsets). Plan to use a GND plane, and SMT bypass caps right by the PowerDriver VDD pin.